# Converting nested list of strings into nested list of characters in a specific order python

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, nested-lists

I have a list of lists something like this:

```
list_example = [['one', 'two', 'thr'], ['fou','fiv','six']]
```

Goal is to have each of the characters from the strings in broken up into a new list, where each list has the character in order of appearance in each string (complicated to explain, but like this):

```
new_list = [[['o', 't', 't'], ['n', 'w', 'h'], ['e', 'o', 'r']], [['f','f','s'],['o','i','i'],['u','v','x']]]
```

I've written a code that works with just one chunk:

```
list_one = ['one', 'two', 'thr']
broken_up_data = []
for i in range(0, 3):
     list_broken_up = [seq[i] for seq in list_one]
     broken_up_data.append(list_broken_up)
print(broken_up_data)
>[['o', 't', 't'], ['n', 'w', 'h'], ['e', 'o', 'r']]
```

But when I try to loop across all of the lists, I get:

```
list_example = [['one', 'two', 'thr'], ['fou','fiv','six']]
broken_up_data = []
for x in list_example:
    for i in range(0, 3):
        list_broken_up = [seq[i] for seq in list_example]
        broken_up_data.append(list_broken_up)
print(broken_up_data)
>[['one', 'fou'], ['two', 'fiv'], ['thr', 'six'], ['one', 'fou'], ['two', 'fiv'], ['thr', 'six']]
```

I'm can see that it's grouping the strings by position in the separate strings (i.e., 'one' with 'fou' which both come first), but it's no longer breaking the strings up and is not correctly looping as I want. It's probably a simple fix in the way I'm setting this up?

Comment: @falsetru gives an excellent example of `zip(*(iterable))` here to solve this problem, but I should point out your nested `for` loops in your last code block, where you do `for x in list_example` but also `for seq in list_example` further down. You appear to be mixing list comprehensions and `for` loops, where in this case one is effectively the other. It can take a while to gain familiarity with list comprehensions, but roughly:
`[[[letter for letter in word] for word in list] for list in list_example]`
is equivalent to: `for list in list_example: for word in list: for letter in word:`

Comment: Ahh, yes thank you! This is really helpful and the type of clarification I was also looking for on my initial approach there. Obviously I'm still trying to get the hang of python (and find it hard to keep track of what I'm doing if I have too many list comprehensions but also hard with so many nested for loops)

Comment: No problem! There are some bits of python that can take a while if you're coming from other languages, but once you get them make perfect sense. In this particular situation however, where you wish to grab items concurrently from two or more lists/tuples/iterables and aggregate them, the most pythonic way is definitely using `zip` - a very useful function! I'd suggest finding a tutorial that works for you to understand and get used to `zip(iter)` and `zip(*iter)` if you see yourself processing this kind of situation in the future. `for x, y in enumerate(Z)`, and `yield` instead of `return` too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), you can aggregate elements. (getting pairs of first elements, second elements, ...)

```
>>> ['one', 'two', 'thr']
['one', 'two', 'thr']
>>> zip(*['one', 'two', 'thr'])
<zip object at 0x7f68226f4d80>
>>> list(zip(*['one', 'two', 'thr']))
[('o', 't', 't'), ('n', 'w', 'h'), ('e', 'o', 'r')]

# To get lists, not tuples
>>> list(map(list, zip(*['one', 'two', 'thr'])))
[['o', 't', 't'], ['n', 'w', 'h'], ['e', 'o', 'r']]
# or
>>> [list(x) for x in zip(*['one', 'two', 'thr'])]
[['o', 't', 't'], ['n', 'w', 'h'], ['e', 'o', 'r']]
```

Applying above to the given list (+ list comprehension)

```py
>>> list_example = [['one', 'two', 'thr'], ['fou','fiv','six']]
>>> [list(zip(*x)) for x in list_example]
[[('o', 't', 't'), ('n', 'w', 'h'), ('e', 'o', 'r')], [('f', 'f', 's'), ('o', 'i', 'i'), ('u', 'v', 'x')]]
>>> [list(map(list, zip(*x))) for x in list_example]
[[['o', 't', 't'], ['n', 'w', 'h'], ['e', 'o', 'r']], [['f', 'f', 's'], ['o', 'i', 'i'], ['u', 'v', 'x']]]
```

Comment: This does the trick! So much simpler than I thought it was...thank you. Is the way I approached it initially completely inefficient then?

Comment: @user14278898, `zip` does similiar thing. But, `zip` does not require you to specify `3` (length of items in list), it returns iterator - it will not consumed eagerly (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the link! I really appreciate it